# pass parameter to jpa converter

Tags: java, jpa, converters

I am trying to write a generic `Converter` to be used in multiple similar cases in my code. I have a set of subclasses that I want to handle using only one `Converter`, so I want to pass something (class type / some parameter / etc) to the `Converter` to be able to define

```
public class GenericConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyGenericClass , Integer> {
.
.
.
    public MyGenericClass convertToEntityAttribute(Integer arg0) {
                // return a certain sub class here according to an attribute / an initialization method / etc
            }
```

and in the entities:

```
@Convert( converter = GenericConverter.class \*pass something here\* )
    protected SubClass1 var1;

@Convert( converter = GenericConverter.class \*pass something here\* )
    protected SubClass2 var2;

@Convert( converter = GenericConverter.class, \*pass something here\* )
    protected SubClass3 var3;
```

Is this doable by any means?

Comment: In order to be useful, we need more specifics about your subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass something (class type / some parameter / etc) to the Converter to be able to define

The only way I see is to make the `GenericConverter` abstract, define a constructor with the parameters you would like to modify

```
public abstract GenericConverter {

   protected GenericConverter(Class<?> type, String someParameter, Object etc){
       ....
   }
}
```

create subclasses and pass that arguments.

```
public class SubClass1Converter extends GenericConverter {

    public SubClass1Converter(){
        super(SubClass1.class, "someValue", ....);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the subclasses in the `@Convert`.

```
@Convert(converter = SubClass1Converter.class)
```

I don't see other good options since the [`AttributeConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) interface does not pass you the [`Field`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) ([`AnnotatedElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html)) that is converted. Thus you can't create an own annotation and lookup this one.

Comment: thanks, a good idea, I was just trying to avoid defining a converter for each class -even if its body is empty-, however I will test it and if I found no better answer I will select it as the accepted answer

Comment: @osamayaccoub If you find a better answer you can answer your own question. I m interessted in other solutions.

Comment: Link sure I will

Comment: subclasses doesn't work with EclipseLink (fine with Hibernate). With payara5, you'll get this message : ''The default table generator could not locate or convert a java type (class gbt.osmoze.model.osmoze.QuoteMode) into a database type for database field (Securities.quote_mode). The generator uses "java.lang.String" as default java type for the field.]]''